# Websphere Federated Repository Authentication Bug?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ldap, websphere, federated, multiple-repositories

I am new to Websphere and am trying to connect to my orgs ldap repo using federated repositories on websphere. I am encountering a strange issue where, when hitting apply

under Global security > Federated repositories > Manage repositories > NFCU-LDAP-Repository

as well as when on the test query page, I get the following error:

`CWWIM5020E  Could not connect to the ldap://my-company-repo.net:389 repository using properties: [certificateMapMode=exactdn],[bindPassword=****],[referal=ignore],[certificateFilter=],[securityDomainName=admin],[bindDN=uid=myusername,ou=people,o=nfcu],[sslConfiguration=],[primary_host=my-company-repo.net],[port=389],[sslEnabled=false],[host=my-company-repo.net],[connectTimeout=20],[id=MYCOMPANY-LDAP-Repository],[ldapServerType=NDS],[authentication=simple]. Exception occurred: javax.naming.AuthenticationException.`

However, under the same two pages, if I simply re-type my password, it will work. By "work I mean the "apply" goes thru with no error, and the test query returns the correct information. Any idea what is going on here?

***Version Info***
I am using Websphere application server traditional  v8.5 or 8.5.5.10

Java version 1.8_0_311 (jdk 1.8_0_311, jre 1.8_0_311)

Apache Maven Version 3.8.3

Comment: if "the "apply" goes thru with no error, and the test query returns the correct information" then it should be ok. Are you sure that in addition to "Apply" you did Save/Synchronize and restart the server?

Comment: It will go through with no error only after re-typing the password. When I exit those screens and re-open them, it will not go through, until I re-type the password. I am saving and restarting server as well, but each time I exit either of those screens and open them again, the error returns until I re-type the pwd. It does not seem to be working because my application is failing to run on the server

Comment: Format your question a bit better. Add version info.

Comment: @jgp how is that

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be hitting a error where the password field is being pre-filled with asterisks instead of the actual password when the page is loaded. Re-type in the password as a work-around.

I delivered a fix for this a while back. See the following link for more details.

- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PI72154

Comment: Ah nice find, I am using the websphere application server traditional v8.5, I will figure out how to apply that fix and let you know if that works

Comment: Might take a while, I don't have the right permissions to apply the fix or even update to a newer version for my company